# Бинарный поиск через рекурсию завершается с ошибкой

Tags: python

Не возвращается None, когда переданного элемента нет в массиве. Пробовал через else - то же самое

```
myArr=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

def bin_search(arr,n):
    low=0
    high=len(arr)-1
    mid=(low+high)//2
    guess=arr[mid]
    if guess==n:
        print('it is here')
    if guess < n:
        return bin_search(arr[(mid+1):],n)
    if guess > n:
        return bin_search(arr[:mid],n)
    return None 
bin_search(myArr,15)
```

Comment: Какой ошибкой завершается? Скопируйте текст сюда ошибки.

Comment: У вас в некоторый момент в `bin_search` передаётся пустой список и на моменте `guess=arr[mid]` идёт обращение к пустому списку, отсюда и ошибка.

Comment: А что этот поиск найдет? Позицию элемента в каком-то подмассиве на неопределенном шаге рекурсии?

Comment: Jazzis, подскажите как исправить? добавил еще одно условие для пустого списка-тоже ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

У вас в некоторый момент в приведенном примере в `bin_search` передаётся пустой список, поэтому в строке `guess=arr[mid]` идёт обращение к пустому списку, отсюда и ошибка. Можете например так сделать:

```python
def bin_search(arr,n):
    if len(arr) == 0:
        return None
    low=0
    high=len(arr)-1
    mid=(low+high)//2
    guess=arr[mid]
    if guess==n:
        print('it is here')
    if guess < n:
        return bin_search(arr[(mid+1):],n)
    if guess > n:
        return bin_search(arr[:mid],n)
    return None
```

Кстати, у вас в любом случае вернется `None`. Поскольку `print` не прерывает выполнение кода после него, а лишь печатает что было передано в него, и продолжает выполнение кода.

Советую вместо `print` использовать всё же `return`  — он останавливает выполнение текущей подпрограммы (функции), возвращает выполнение к месту её вызова и, опционально, устанавливает возвращаемое значение функции.

Comment: Вы запускали программу? Я так уже делал, только вместо [ if len(arr) == 0: return None ] я писал [ if arr == []: print('nope') ]. Программа печатает 'nope' но после этого тот же код ошибки.

Comment: @НикитаШиляев `print` не прерывает выполнение кода внутри функции; я немножко изменил ответ с учетом вашего комментария;

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def bin_search(arr, n, low = 0):
...     if arr:
...         high = len(arr) - 1
...         mid = (low + high) // 2
...         guess = arr[mid]
...         if guess == n:
...             print('it is here')
...         if guess < n:
...             return bin_search(arr[(mid + 1):], n)
...         if guess > n:
...             return bin_search(arr[:mid], n)
>>> myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> bin_search(myArr, 3)
it is here
>>> bin_search(myArr, 15)
```